# Main method error in superclass/subclass program

Tags: java, subclass, program-entry-point, superclass

Just edited this so it shows all of the code.  Hopefully it's a little bit more helpful

I can't figure out how to declare a main method for my program.

This is how I tried it and I got about 45 errors, mainly illegal exceptions:

```
public class Rectangle1{

private double width;
private double height;

public Rectangle1(){
}


public Rectangle1(double width, double height){
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    }

public double getWidth(){
    return width;
    }

public void setWidth(double width) {
    this.width = width;
    }


public double getHeight(){
    return height;
    }

public void setHeight(double height){
    this.height = height;
    }

public double getArea(){
    return width * height;
    }

public double getPerimeter(){
    return 2 * (width + height);
    }
public static void main (String [] args){
}
}
```

Comment: What are the errors exactly?

Comment: This might be a stupid question but are you closing your brackets?

Comment: Maybe it's because you're missing some closing brakets?

Comment: This is just the first part of the code, the closing main method bracket is at the end like usual.  Here's the first error:        Rectangle1.java:14: error: illegal start of expression
    public Rectangle1(double width, double height){

Comment: Have you looked at a beginning Java tutorial? This is pretty much boiler plate stuff, and you should be able to figure this out just by using what the tut's show you to do.

Comment: @BrettSteen That statement doesn't appear in the code you've posted.

Comment: You appear to be trying to nest a constructor within the main method. Again, please read through and go through some tutorials. You can't succeed by guessing at it.

Comment: With your edits it's like trying to shoot a moving target. Please tell us what your code *really* looks like. Is this the final version for the question? Are you sure?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes it's the final version.  No need to be rude.

Comment: Sorry for the rudeness, but it's very frustrating to try to figure out what could possibly be wrong when you don't take care to post the actual code that may be causing the problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I understand, but I was ridiculed for posting my full code in an earlier question today, so I thought I shouldn't do it again.  It's my first day using the site, so I don't know all of the etiquette quite yet.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be sure that you're closing all your brackets

```
public class Rectangle1{

    private double width;
    private double height;

public Rectangle1(){
}

public static void main (String [] args){

}

public Rectangle1(double width, double height){
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    }

}
```

It's possible that you are, but you just aren't showing your code, I'll remove if you are closing them.

Edit: I changed my code to match your new code.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a constructor *inside* your main method (`public Rectangle1(double width, double height){...`). Move it outside of the method. Also, it should go without saying that you will have to close all your brackets.

```
public class Rectangle1 {

    private double width;
    private double height;

    public Rectangle1() {
    }

    public Rectangle1(double width, double height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Just as a note, you will probably find your code a whole lot easier to manage/update if you indent it properly, as I've done above.

---

***EDIT***: Upon seeing your edited code, it looks like you're declaring basically everything in the main method (this is why you're getting so many errors)... move all that junk out and into the class body itself.